# How many concurrent requests per route can Spark support?

Tags: spark-java

I need to handle many (~1000) concurrent requests per route but Spark seems to process them sequentially.  Is there some configuration parameter I can set?

Answer (score 1):

Spark has a 200 thread ThreadPool. Typically 1000 requests shouldn't be a problem unless they're very slow requests. You can configure the ThreadPool, but it probably won't help if you've noticed the server can't handle your load. If you need a simple framework like Spark which supports async handling, you can check out https://javalin.io/

Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer for both Spark and Javalin.

Comment: I tried with threadPool set to 1024 and the observed behaviour was to queue 2 requests to the same endpoint (which just waited for 20 seconds) and process them sequentially.  Is the expected behaviour?

Comment: No, that's not expected, they should run concurrently.

Comment: This might be my browser queuing the requests.  I'll do a more representative test.

Comment: Yes, browsers have a very short limit for parallel requests to the same endpoint.